# Typescript - pass new key in object as generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I was curious how to implement this kind of thing:

I have array of objects passing to the chart Component for example:

```js
type ChartData = { label: string; value: number }[];
const data: ChartData = [{ label: "Mon", value: 3 }, { label: "Tue", value: 7 }];
```

In some cases however, I need instead of `value` key something different. How I can create generic type from ChartData so I would have objects with key equals to string passed to generic.

For example:

```js
type ChartData<T> = { label: string; [T]: number }[];

type NewType = ChartData<"newkey">
const data: NewType = [{ label: "Mon", newkey: 3 }, { label: "Tue", newkey: 7 }]; // OK
```

Any ideas how to do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could do this:

```
type ChartData<K extends keyof any = "value"> =
    Array<{ label: string; } & Record<K, number>>;
```

This uses the [`Record<K, number>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) which is a useful type alias for the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{[P in K]: number}`.  So you could also use:

```
type ChartData<K extends keyof any = "value"> =
    Array<{ label: string; } & {[P in K]: number}>;
```

That works the way you're trying to use it:

```
const data: ChartData = [{ label: "Mon", value: 3 }, { label: "Tue", value: 7 }];

type NewType = ChartData<"newkey">
const newData: NewType = [{ label: "Mon", newkey: 3 }, { label: "Tue", newkey: 7 }];
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwE7ACIOAgPAaShAD2AgDsATAZygGsIQB7AMygRJCgF4oAiANwQA2AVwjcAfJwBQUGVACCSJAhBYA3lAEIARhAEAuKBWBIAliQDmAbigBfKADIoAJQgBjekjK4ANFBJCAWx0kMTFrSUl3EiMoMgwEA3hkNHjOKABtdU0dfR4AWXoSbl9+YQgDAGZbXyztXQNuABURYqhSkQMAdlsAXUsI0EgoADkIAHdG8GguJJR0TCxuEnHaEHFIwpjlsfmEkfHJoa5MjTrc7gKi323VyuqoWpyG5tFrlbou3v7JIA)